# Set up ouput-list names in slider::slide_index()

Tags: r, list, rolling-computation

`slider::slider_index()` uses a `purrr::map()`-like syntax to apply functions on rolling (here time) window. The output of this function is a list. My question is, **how to set up the names of this list?**

The `slider_index()` function does not have a `.names_to` argument like `slider_index_dfr()`.

See reproducible example below:

```r
library(slider)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

storms_summary <- storms %>% 
  # filter dataset so it does not eat all memory and save computing time ;)
  filter(year <= 2000 & year >= 1999) %>% 
  # make a date column to mimic my real data
  mutate(storm_date = as.Date(paste(year, month, day, sep = "-"))) %>% 
  arrange(storm_date) %>% 
  slider::slide_index(
    .x = .,
    .i = .$storm_date,
    .f = ~ summary(.x),
    .after = lubridate::weeks(2),
    .complete = TRUE
  )
```

Expected output is the list `storms_summary` with names that are character strings indicating the first and the last date of the period summarized. With the code below we get:

```
> names(storms_summary)
NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no way to assign the names within the function we can create names on our own and use `setNames` to assign it.

```
library(slider)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

storms_summary <- storms %>% 
  # filter dataset so it does not eat all memory and save computing time ;)
  filter(year <= 2000 & year >= 1999) %>% 
  # make a date column to mimic my real data
  mutate(storm_date = as.Date(paste(year, month, day, sep = "-"))) %>% 
  arrange(storm_date) %>% 
  mutate(sliding_output = slider::slide_index(.x = cur_data(), 
    .i = storm_date,
    .f = ~summary(.x),
    .after = lubridate::weeks(2),
    .complete = TRUE
  ), 
  names = slider::slide_index_chr(.x = storm_date, 
                              .i = storm_date, 
                              .f = ~paste0(range(.x), collapse = '-'),
                              .after = lubridate::weeks(2)), 
  sliding_output = setNames(sliding_output, names)) %>%
  select(-names)

names(storms_summary$sliding_output)

# [1] "1999-07-02-1999-07-03" "1999-07-03-1999-07-03" "1999-07-03-1999-07-03"
# [4] "1999-07-03-1999-07-03" "1999-08-24-1999-09-07" "1999-08-24-1999-09-07"
# [7] "1999-08-24-1999-09-07" "1999-08-25-1999-09-08" "1999-08-25-1999-09-08"
#[10] "1999-08-25-1999-09-08" "1999-08-25-1999-09-08" "1999-08-26-1999-09-09"
#...
#...
```